# angular typescript assigned Date to DateConstructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am passing a date value from a selected angular gridrow to my modal popup. One of the field is a Date field.

In my typescript, I got the databinding object defined as

```
public request = {

"MeetingDate": Date
};
```

When I call the function to open the modal popup,

```
editModal(content, selectedRow) {

const mdt = new Date(selectedRow.meetingDate);
const mm = mdt.getmonth();
this.request.meetingDate = { 'year': mdt.getFullYear(),  'month': mm, 'day': mdt.getDate() };

this.modalService.open(content);
}
```

I am getting an error stating

Type '{ 'year': number; 'month': numberl 'day': number; }' is not assigna ble to to type DateConstructor

Object literal may only specify konw properties, and ''year'' does not exist in type 'DateConstructor'

I tried a few other methods like this.request.meetingDate = selectedMeetingDt but the value does not show up on the UI datepicker. I also tried meetingDate = new Date(...) but that is not working either.

Even though I declare the property to be Date, in the function, the cursor is show me that its a DateConstructor.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `const mm - mdt.getmonth();` is this line correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone ever encounter this error on Angular Typescript,

Originally I databinded the datepicker with this object

public meetingRequest = {
    "MeetingDt":  Date,
    "PublicDate": Date,
    };

I had to move the Date fields outside the object to get it to build. In my Save function,

I had to do something like this

meetingRequest.meetingDate = this.MeetingDate.ToDateString();

This got me pass the issue and its working, but it should have worked with the object which I am using to pass to the web api. Wierd!